# hex_md5 implementation

Tags: c#

Is there an identical `hex_md5` algorithm in C# to this: http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/md5.html

I've looked at the RFC 1321, but I wasn't sure if this was a custom implementation based on RFC 1321. I need it to be identical i.e. the value that `hex_md5` would return in the JavaScript implementation will be the same in the C# implementation (if one exists).

Comment: You just asked this question no more than 5 minutes ago....

Comment: I deleted the question because I failed to include some important points.

Comment: "Are you sure you want to delete?" - Slipped Twice??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fairly typical implementation that should match the library's:

```
string dataToHash = "aaa";
byte[] dataToHashBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataToHash);
using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
{
    var hashed = md5.ComputeHash(dataToHashBytes);
    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(hashed).Replace("-", ""));
}
```

The C# code produces `47BCE5C74F589F4867DBD57E9CA9F808`. This is fairly trivial code, it takes a string, "aaa", converts it to a a byte representation using the ASCII encoding, then hashes it. Finally, we covert it to hexadecimal.

And here is a JSFiddle from the library producing the same thing: http://jsfiddle.net/QC57K/

Comment: You'll also need to include a `using System.Security.Cryptography;` to access the MD5 class.

Comment: Tested both implementations. Works fine, except the C# produces uppercase characters, and the JavaScript implementation produces lowercase. Is case sensitivity relevant in MD5 hashes?

Comment: Uppercase only matters to the content

Comment: @JamesJeffery hexadecimal is just a representation of binary data. The binary data is the same, when it's converted to hex, you can use uppercase letters, or lowercase. So it only matters if some other library or function says it matters. If it does, call `ToLower()` on the string.